# How to structure the flex column using css flex

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

Below is the code which I am trying to accomplish for desktop and tablet view. please suggest how can I achieve the output for the tablet view.

```
     <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="item first">1</div>
        <div class="item second">2</div>
        <div class="item third">3</div>
    </div>
  <style>
   .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        background: #f9f8f6;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .flex-container .item{
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      height: 5rem;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: At first blush I'd say you might want a flex within a flex. Outer has two items and the right item is s flex with two items. Each of these flexes has a different behavior.

Comment: I'd suggest using the right tool for the job; since you want your display to adapt from a one-dimensional layout to a two-dimensional layout, I'd recommend using CSS Grid instead of flexbox.